# Drag and Drop attachments to Outlook from Metadata driven SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, attachments, drag-and-drop

I am currently have prepared a library with a few thousand files which is driven completely by metadata and it works AMAZING, however, I get a lot of issues with metadata library if I am trying to send someone a file via email, or upload a file from email.

To do these tasks I always have to download the file to my computer and only then I can drag and drop to SharePoint or Outlook. I tried to use link attachment but then it just throws me a list of files with no possibility to filter on metadata. Is there any way to make fully Metadata driven library work at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop emails and/or attachments from Outlook to SharePoint using Chrome and Edge. Unfortunately there is no OOTB support for metadata. There are solutions that add metadata functionality. e.g. [here](https://www.slimapplications.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/ExplorerUploadOverview_2Labels.png)
Users can drag and drop emails and/or attachments from Outlook directly to SharePoint. Some of the solutions will then automatically extract the email metadata (e.g. subject, from, sent date, ...) and create a unique name. There are also solutions that allow setting custom metadata (e.g. customer ID) for the emails. This part only helps getting files into SharePoint with the proper metadata.